# Changing background-colour with css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change a background color to yellow with JavaScript, but setting background colour to yellow doesn't work.

```
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3">.
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<script>
  function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle('change');
  }
</script>
```

Css

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 39px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-345deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 6;
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

I thought it was just a matter of adding `background-color:yellow` onto the css. I'd also like to change the width, can this be done by adding width 500px; onto tye end of the animation?

Comment: Your `.change .bar3` selector is inside the `.change .bar2`. Nesting is not possible in plain CSS. But I assume this is a typo?

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean? That it's indented more?

Comment: Look closer below the line `transform: rotate(3000deg);` and look how it is different from the rest of your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your rule for `.change .bar2` using `}`, then it'll work:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 39px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-345deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 6;
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3">.</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Emiel Zuurbier commented, there is a typo on your CSS:

```
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 6;
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

Must be changed to:

```
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 6;
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing great, also you have structured your CSS file very well as well as you have written the DOM manipulation correctly. There is just a typo of closing the brace `}` of `.change .bar2` class.

You just have to change your CSS file.

From this-

```
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 6;
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

To this -

```
.change .bar2 {
      opacity: 6;
      transform: rotate(3000deg);
}
.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

And everything will be great.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, there is been a typo, following code worked.

```js
const myFunction = (x) => {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 39px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-345deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 6;
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
}
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3">.</div>
  </div>
</a>
```